# Em um DataFrame, modificar dados de uma coluna condicionado ao valor de outra coluna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conversão

Estou trabalhando numa automação com relatórios para resultados de operaçõesos de compra e venda de criptomoedas/ações.

Preciso converter o valor positivo de uma célula para negativo caso ela seja compra(BUY). E quando é uma operação de venda(SELL) não preciso alterar nada. Já está positivo e se manterá assim.

Abaixo segue o exemplo do DataFrame original:

[image: Exemplo de um DataFrame que precisa ter na coluna Amount valores negativos quando a operação na coluna Side for de BUY]

O resultado final para a coluna Amount entre as linhas 4 e 9 deveria ser um valor negativo.
Logo, tenho que condicionar a alteração da coluna Amount à presença do valor BUY na coluna Side.

Tentei usar a função .loc do Pandas. Mas travei na operação de conversão do valor original para o valor negativo.

```
df.loc[df.Side=='BUY','Amount']="aqui preciso inserir a fórmula para multiplicar por -1"
```

Fiz um teste colocando uma variável fixa e funciona. Então, preciso só do comando certo de conversão ou então usar outra função.

Ex:

```
df.loc[df.Side=='BUY','Amount']='negativo'
```

[image: Exemplo que a alteração funciona. Só falta o comando adequado.]

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 3):

Além da sugestão do @Augusto Vasques, você pode utilizar o loc como você havia tentado anteriormente:

```
df.loc[df['Side'] == 'BUY', 'Amount'] = -df['Amount']
```

Loc + isin

```
df.loc[df['Side'].isin(['BUY']), 'Amount'] = -df['Amount']
```

Comment: Suas duas sugestões funcionaram. Inclusive a primeira é a mais simples dentro da linha de raciocínio que eu estava construindo. Muito óbvia e me faltou apenas saber escrever. Obrigado.

Comment: @HeduanPinheiro, por nada! Grande Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

Para alterar valores numa coluna onde dependa de valores em outras colunas, use o método [`Series.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html#pandas.Series.mask) que substitui valores onde dadas condições sejam verdadeiras.

Exemplo:
Na coluna *Amount*, `df["Amount"]`, onde a condição, `df["Side"]=="BUY"`, for verdadeira substitui in loco, `inplace=True`,  o valor pelo seu simétrico aditivo, `-df["Amount"]`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Pair":["BAKEBUSD", "BAKEBUSD", "BAKEBUSD", "BAKEBUSD", "BAKEBUSD", "BAKEBUSD", "BAKEBUSD", "BAKEBUSD", "BAKEBUSD", "BAKEBUSD", "CAKEUSDT"],
    "Side":["SELL", "SELL", "SELL", "SELL", "BUY", "BUY", "BUY", "BUY", "BUY", "BUY", "SELL"],
    "Amount":[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0]
})

print("DF Original", df, sep="\n")

df["Amount"].mask(df["Side"]=="BUY", -df["Amount"], inplace=True)

print("DF Modificado", df, sep="\n")
```

Resultado:

```
DF Original
        Pair  Side  Amount
0   BAKEBUSD  SELL     1.0
1   BAKEBUSD  SELL     2.0
2   BAKEBUSD  SELL     3.0
3   BAKEBUSD  SELL     4.0
4   BAKEBUSD   BUY     5.0
5   BAKEBUSD   BUY     6.0
6   BAKEBUSD   BUY     7.0
7   BAKEBUSD   BUY     8.0
8   BAKEBUSD   BUY     9.0
9   BAKEBUSD   BUY    10.0
10  CAKEUSDT  SELL    11.0
DF Modificado
        Pair  Side  Amount
0   BAKEBUSD  SELL     1.0
1   BAKEBUSD  SELL     2.0
2   BAKEBUSD  SELL     3.0
3   BAKEBUSD  SELL     4.0
4   BAKEBUSD   BUY    -5.0
5   BAKEBUSD   BUY    -6.0
6   BAKEBUSD   BUY    -7.0
7   BAKEBUSD   BUY    -8.0
8   BAKEBUSD   BUY    -9.0
9   BAKEBUSD   BUY   -10.0
10  CAKEUSDT  SELL    11.0
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/JubilantScaredFirewall#main.py)</sup>

Comment: Sua sugestão funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!